# Extracting nodes based on token size in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt

I am completely new to XSL and am trying to learn a few things. Suppose I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
    <Node>
        <node-id>1</node-id>
        <node-path>2,3</node-path>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <node-id>2</node-id>
        <node-path>2,3,4</node-path>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <node-id>3</node-id>
        <node-path>123,34</node-path>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <node-id>4</node-id>
        <node-path>2124,14,14</node-path>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <node-id>5</node-id>
        <node-path>1,0</node-path>
    </Node>
</Result>
```

and I want to get all the nodes that have only two values in the node-path field like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Result>
    <Node>
        <node-id>1</node-id>
        <node-path>2,3</node-path>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <node-id>3</node-id>
        <node-path>123,34</node-path>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <node-id>5</node-id>
        <node-path>1,0</node-path>
    </Node>
</Result>
```

How would I do this in XSL? Since I need to copy the nodes, I figured out that I have to use the identity transformation as a template. I also saw that we should use recursion to count the tokens. I came up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template name="root-nodes">
        <xsl:for-each select="/Result/Node">
            <xsl:variable name="path" select="node-path" />
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenizer" mode="matcher">
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$path" />
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Could not figure out how to write this recursion -->
    <xsl:template name="tokenizer" mode="matcher">
        <xsl:param name="list"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($list,$delimiter)" />
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenizer">
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,$delimiter)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I am having problems with the recursion piece. How can I count the tokens and make sure that I do the identity transform only if the count is 2? How can I fix the recursion template? What is the problem in my existing "tokenizer" template (it is not even giving me the tokens)? Any additional resources/links would be very good.

Comment: if you use xslt 2.0 use replace() to extract the values​​, width regex.
http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_replace.html

Comment: You've tagged the question "xslt-1.0" but your stylesheet says `version="2.0"` - which do you actually want?

Comment: @Ian Roberts : Sorry. That was a mistake. Corrected it. I want 1.0

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Node[string-length(translate(node-path, ',', '')) != (string-length(node-path) - 1)]"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

suffices.

Comment: Looks like we both had the same thought (if expressed slightly differently).  You win :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since the "nodes that have two values in the path" are the same as the "nodes whose path contains exactly one comma", you can use a trick like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ignore Nodes whose node path does not contain one comma -->
    <xsl:template match="Node[translate(node-path, translate(node-path, ',', ''), '') != ',']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The double-translate trick is a useful one to know, it provides a way to strip out all characters from a string *except* those in a whitelist.  In this case we're removing all non-comma characters from the path and then checking whether what we're left with is a single comma.

Comment: Isn't the outer `translate` call missing one argument (of the three required arguments)?